# How do I create an absolute URL from two components, in Perl?

Tags: perl, url, join

Suppose I have:

```
my $a = "http://site.com";
my $part = "index.html";
my $full = join($a,$part);
print $full;
>> http://site.com/index.html
```

What do I have to use as `join`, in order to get my snippet to work?

EDIT: I'm looking for something more general. What if `a` ends with a slash, and `part` starts with one? I'm sure in some module, someone has this covered.

Comment: wrong use of join -> join("/",$a,$part);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [URI::Split](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI/Split.pm), e.g.:

```
use URI::Split qw(uri_join);
$uri = uri_join('http', 'site.com', 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
use URI;
URI->new("index.html")->abs("http://site.com")
```

will produce

```
"http://site.com/index.html"
```

URI->abs will take care of merging the paths properly following your uri specification,

so

```
URI->new("/bah")->abs("http://site.com/bar")
```

will produce

```
"http://site.com/bah"
```

and

```
URI->new("index.html")->abs("http://site.com/barf")
```

will produce

```
"http://site.com/barf/index.html"
```

and

```
URI->new("../uplevel/foo")->abs("http://site.com/foo/bar/barf")
```

will produce

```
"http://site.com/foo/uplevel/foo"
```

alternatively, there's a shortcut sub in URI namespace that I just noticed:

```
URI->new_abs($url, $base_url)
```

so

```
URI->new_abs("index.html", "http://site.com")
```

will produce

```
"http://site.com/index.html"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

No need for ‘join‘, just use string interpolation.

```
my $a = "http://site.com";
my $part = "index.html";
my $full = "$a/$part";
print $full;
>> http://site.com/index.html
```

**Update:**

Not everything requires a module.  CPAN is wonderful, but restraint is needed.

The simple approach above works very well if you have clean inputs.  If you need to handle unevenly formatted strings, you will need to normalize them somehow.  Using a library in the URI namespace that meets your needs is probably the best course of action if you need to handle user input.  If the variance is minor `File::Spec` or a little manual clean-up may be good enough for your needs.

```
my $a = 'http://site.com';
my @paths = qw( /foo/bar foo  //foo/bar );

# bad paths don't work:
print join "\n", "Bad URIs:", map "$a/$_", @paths;

my @cleaned = map s:^/+::, @paths;
print join "\n", "Cleaned URIs:", map "$a/$_", @paths;
```

When you have to handle bad stuff like `$path = /./foo/.././foo/../foo/bar;` is when you want definitely want to use a library.  Of course, this could be sorted out using `File::Spec`'s cannonical path function.

If you are worried about bad/bizarre stuff in the URI rather than just path issues (usernames, passwords, bizarre protocol specifiers) or URL encoding of strings, then using a URI library is really important, and is indisputably not overkill.

Comment: Yeah, but what if $a ends with /, and $part starts with it?

Comment: If you have complex needs, use a complex library.  If you have simple needs and sanitzed inputs, use a simple approach.  Although handling a trailing or leading slash is not exactly complex.  You will have more problems if you don't read the perldoc for join and try to use it improperly (your sample code doesn't do what you think it does-to concatenate your URI elements with `join`, you should be using `join'/', $a, $part;`).  You can also use `File::Spec` to concatenate your paths.  Scale your solution to your problem set and dependencies with care.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this, an implementation of a function similar to Python's urljoin, but in Perl:

http://sveinbjorn.org/urljoin_function_implemented_using_Perl

Answer (score 1):

As I am used to Java `java.net.URL` methods, I was looking for a similar way to concatenate URI without any assumption about scheme, host or port (in my case, it is for possibly complex Subversion URL):

```
http://site.com/page/index.html
 +  images/background.jpg
=>  http://site.com/page/images/background.jpg
```

Here is the way to do it in Perl:

```
use URI;
my $base = URI->new("http://site.com/page/index.html");
my $result = URI->new_abs("images/background.jpg", $base);
```